# Is there a way to use mongodump and specify several collections to export?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have 20 collections in my db, out of these 20 I need only 5, is it possible to specify which collections I want to export instead of using `--excludeCollectionsWithPrefix` several times. From the docs and my experience it seems that `-c` flag can be specified only once, so something like `mongodump --uri "mongodb://..." -o ./db-dump -c a -c b -c d -c f` won't work

**UPDATE**
Also, is it possible to use regex with `--excludeCollectionsWithPrefix`?

Comment: Looks like things didn't improve since this post :) http://tech.tulentsev.com/2012/03/how-to-dump-your-mongodb-database-partially-only-selected-tables/

Comment: You could run a `.sh`  or `.py` script to build the command for you and at the end just run on your terminal.